# JSON.parse not working with JSON string returned from an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a piece of JavaScript that gets data from a backend with an ajax call. There is a JSON string returned and I cannot work out why the JSON.parse is not working.

Here is my code

```
var success_get = (jQuery).ajax({
  url: "<?php echo base_path(); ?>reservation/success_get",
  method: "GET",
  async: "true"
});
```

In Firefox I look at the console and I see the JSON returned for success_get is

```
{"Reservations":[{"Id":"415b68e9-1209-4ca9-9f6b-47116ced1769","ExtraDuration":0,"TotalDuration":1,"CreationTime":"2016-02-08T00:22:59+11:00","ExpiryTime":"2016-02-08T00:32:28+11:00","Sender":{"ReturnOption":"Dispose","ReturnAddress":null,"Id":"044bf5b5-95cd-44d1-a22a-8070b45a26ba","FirstName":"Test","LastName":"User","Email":"web@tz.net","Phone":"85112366"},"Recipient":{"Id":"b53ad6ac-9750-44c8-9bdd-581e89d3be93","FirstName":"Test","LastName":"User","Email":"test@test.com","Phone":"12345678"},"KioskCode":"Hm1","LockerSize":"Small","LockerNumber":"I5","Total":4.5}],"TotalAmount":4.5,"Sender":{"ReturnOption":"Dispose","ReturnAddress":null,"Id":"044bf5b5-95cd-44d1-a22a-8070b45a26ba","FirstName":"Test","LastName":"User","Email":"web@tz.net","Phone":"85112366"},"NumberOfHoursForDropOff":47}
```

And that looks like valid JSON as far as I can tell

I am then doing the following

```
success_get.done(function( success ) {
  object_rsuccess = JSON.parse(success);
  console.log(object_rsuccess);

});
```

In Firefox I get the error

```
ReferenceError: object_rsuccess is not defined
```

However in the console.log I am seeing

```
Object { Reservations=[1],  TotalAmount=4.5,  Sender={...},  more...}
```

And when I expand the sections in braces I am seeing the data I would expect to see.

I would have thought that I could see the variables, eg TotalAmount by doing the following

```
var totalamount = object_rsuccess.TotalAmount;
```

But this will not work while I am getting the error for object_rsuccess not defined.

Am I missing something or simply making a silly mistake?

Comment: You could make a promise. You got to have your foundaments in javascript...

Comment: That doesn't really seem possible, if the `done` handler executes `object_rsuccess` would be defined regardless of what the returned data is, you just declared that variable on the previous line ?

Comment: you use **object_rsuccess** variable outside of done method?

Comment: Your `object_rsuccess` should be declared with `var` somewhere.

Comment: Look at my anwser guys..

Comment: @Dsafds the `.done()` API in the OP is already written using the returned promise.

Comment: Oh i didnt know that @Pointy. Sorry guys

Comment: Please show full code context. It sure sounds like you are trying to access data outside of the `done` callback

Comment: (I'd recommend against the advice of making this a global variable. It sounds more like you're trying to access the variable before it's been initialized.)

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your code which will use the `object_rsuccess` in a function:

```
var theFunctionToBeCalled = function(obj){
    var totalamount = obj.TotalAmount;
    console.log(totalamount);
};
```

Then call it within the `.done()`:

```
success_get.done(function(success) {
    var object_rsuccess = JSON.parse(success);
    console.log(object_rsuccess);
    theFunctionToBeCalled(object_rsuccess);
});
```

Your AJAX settings makes the function async, which means the rest of your code continues to be executed and even when you define `object_rsuccess` globally, it will most probably not be available for use when you need it.

Alternative to my suggestion, based on what feels comfortable to you, you can put everything using `object_rsuccess` within the `.done()` or change `async:true` to `async:false`.

Comment: Why? It's an asynchronous function, it's unlikely to be at all useful to have that variable available in that scope (since that scope probably won't exist a moment after the assignment is performed).

Comment: You are right @Quentin. I also realized I missed that point and revized the answer accordingly.